# React-URLSearchParams returning Null object

Tags: reactjs, url-parameters, query-string

I am using the following code to retrieve query parameters from URL but URLSearchParams returns an empty object.

PS: uselocation.search returning correct output.

```
const stringdata = useLocation().search

const queryparameter = new URLSearchParams(stringdata)
    
console.log("query parameter :", queryparameter)
    
const query = queryparameter.get('q');
    
var url_string = `http://localhost:3000/recipes${query}`
```

Comment: you need get a minimal repro set and post a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using window.location.search over user search params.
That should look something like:

```
const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const query = queryParams.get('q');
let url_string = `http://localhost:3000/recipes${query}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

The search property returns the querystring part of a URL, including the question mark (?).

```
const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
```

Then you need to check if `queryparameter.get('q')` exists, otherwise it will return `null` and will append `null` to url.

```
let query;
if(queryParameter.has('q')){
   query = queryparameter.get('q');
}
```

then

```
 var url_string = `http://localhost:3000/recipes/${query}`
```